# subside vs dissipate

Tags: synonyms

I am wondering what is the difference between these two words? I often hear:

- the fear dissipates
- the pain subsides

But what's the real difference?

Also, where can I look for the subtle, or not so subtle, differences of words? Are there any good resources?

Comment: Have you looked at their respective dictionary definitions?

Comment: Yes of course. I feel I can use them exchangeably. That’s why I am asking,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*meta:*
I don't know the OP's level of proficiency in or exposure to the English language and its usage. In general, looking up a word's etymology helps in its correct or preferred usage.

As Kate Bunting already note in an earlier answer, *dissipate* refers to thinning out by spreading in all directions (radially outward), while *subside* refers to lessening to a lower level (vertically downward). However, it's not always that distinct in usage.

etymonline:

> **[subside](https://www.etymonline.com/word/subside#etymonline_v_22265)**: "to sink to the bottom," from *sub* "under, beneath" … + *sidere* "to settle," from PIE root ***sed**- (1) "to sit."
>   
>   **[dissipate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dissipate#etymonline_v_11503)**: early 15c., *dissipaten*, "scatter or drive off in all directions," from Latin *dissipatus*, past participle of *dissipare* "to spread abroad, scatter, disperse; squander, disintegrate," from *dis-* "apart" (see dis-) + *supare* "to throw, scatter," which is apparently from a PIE **supi*- "to throw, sling, cast" …

Pain can **subside** -- become less severe by going to a lower level, or **dissipate** -- become less severe as if by thinning out. Either way, it just means that the pain has eased a bit.

OTOH,

> According to the labour ministry’s labour inspection office, average levels of dust are expected to be higher than the 50 μg/m3 limit on Sunday, but are expected to **subside** by the end of the day. ([Cyprus Mail](https://cyprus-mail.com/2019/01/27/dust-levels-still-high-expected-to-subside-by-the-evening/))
>   
>   After battering Taiwan, the storm had moved inland where it was expected to **dissipate**, but Nina turned north instead, reaching the Huai River basin … ([Ozy](https://www.ozy.com/flashback/230000-died-in-a-dam-collapse-that-china-kept-secret-for-years/91699))

Comment: I am starting to get it. In your other examples, levels of dust can subside but not dissipate. A storm can subside but not dissipate. I wonder how I can use etymology effectively for this purpose. Is there any recommended resources to read about it?

Answer (score 2):

*Dissipate* (in this sense) means to disappear by breaking up (as fog does). *Subside* means to sink to a lower level.

Comment: True but not necessarily, usage wise. The words are often used in a loose sense interchangeably, as OP has observed.

Comment: Which dictionary did you use to find these definitions? I tried several dictionaries but couldn't find these.

Comment: @TomBennett They are my own explanations of the different shades of meaning between the two words, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: That is wonderful. How did you learn to get these shades of the meaning? I want to do that for words but don’t see a reliable way. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've had a lifetime of reading widely and being interested in words!

Comment: That’s good to know. Thank you.